# Guidance needed regarding allocating c structs and arrays on heap in Objective-c

Tags: c, objective-c, memory-leaks, malloc, heap-memory

I am working on my first largish Objective-c application, a card game.  For various reasons, I've elected to maintain the state of my game using a C struct that contains ints, bools, arrays, and various pointers.  (For the curious, I'm doing this because I will ultimately have to make and destroy thousands and thousands of these gameStates and I wanted to be as close to the "bare metal" as possible.)  The gameState structure is defined as follows:

```
struct GameState {
    // changing game state properties
    int score;
    int moves;
    bool won;

    int numberOfCards;
    int numberOfPiles;

    // doneness of piles
    bool *pileDoneness;
    bool *pileDisabled;

    // array of cards (each item is a pointer to a card)
    Card *cards;

    // defining piles (each card in the pile is a pointer to a pointer Card in the cards array)
    Card ***piles;

    // previous gameStates
    struct GameState *previous;
};
```

One note, right before a move is made in a game I make a copy the gameState (all values except for previous) and set gameState->previous to the copy.

A card is just an integer where various bytes represent various card properties (suit, faceup/down, value, etc).

I also have a MDCard class and MDGameState class.  Both of these classes only have class methods and I never create an instance of either.  They have methods on them that can create and manipulate cards and gameStates, respectively.  To explain, you could flip a card using this code:

```
// assume card already exists
[MDCard flip:card];
```

I can get the color of a card like this:

```
Color color = [MDCard color:card];
```

Ok, fine. Now the MDGameState object also has a class method to create a new gameInstance.  This is its code:

```
+(GameState *)newGameStateWithNumberOfPiles:(u_int)numberOfPiles andNumberOfCards:(u_int)numberOfCards{
    // create our new gameState struct
    GameState *gameState = malloc(sizeof(GameState));

    // array of state of doneness of piles
    gameState->pileDoneness = malloc(sizeof(bool) * numberOfPiles);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfPiles ; i++) gameState->pileDoneness[i] = false;

    gameState->pileDisabled = malloc(sizeof(bool) * numberOfPiles);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfPiles ; i++) gameState->pileDisabled[i] = false;

    // array of pointers to cards
    **gameState->cards = malloc(sizeof(Card) * numberOfCards);**
    for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfCards ; i++) gameState->cards[i] = 0;

    // array of array of pointers to Cards in cards array
    gameState->piles = malloc(sizeof(Card **) * numberOfPiles);
    for (int p = 0 ; p < numberOfPiles ; p++){
        gameState->piles[p] = malloc(sizeof(Card *) * numberOfCards);
        for(int c = 0 ; c < numberOfCards ; c++){
            gameState->piles[p][c] = nil;
        }
    }

    gameState->moves = 0;
    gameState->score = 0;
    gameState->won = false;

    // piles
    gameState->numberOfPiles = numberOfPiles;
    gameState->numberOfCards = numberOfCards;
    gameState->previous = nil;

    return gameState;
}
```

My current understanding is that the gameState will be allocated in the heap. Actually, the gameState variable is simply a pointer to the allocated memory in the heap.  That allocated memory in the heap contains various values such as the number of moves, score, won, etc.  It also contains pointers to other allocated memory in the heap for the gameState arrays of cards, piles, etc.  IE: all the mallocs are allocating memory on the heap.

I know that I need to deallocate the memory for this gameState when I'm done with it.

I'm wondering, does Objective-C ARC track references to this gameState struct?  How about to the arrays it references?  I currently assume the answer is no.

I assume that as soon as the gameState is returned from newGameStateWithNumberOfPiles:andNumberOfCards: that the MDGameState class doesn't have a reference to it anymore.  Is this correct?

I assume that the object that ends up with the reference to the gameState is responsible for freeing up its memory when it's done with the gameState?

I need the gameState object to live as long as the user is playing the game.  Again, note that each time the user make a move a copy of the gameState is made and set as the previous gameState.  This is for undo purposes.

I created a function on the MDGameState that is supposed to free up all the memory used by this struct:

```
+ (void)freeGameState:(GameState *)gameState recurse:(BOOL)recurse {
    if(recurse && gameState->previous != nil){
        [MDGameState freeGameState:gameState->previous recurse:recurse];
    }

    for (int p = 0 ; p < gameState->numberOfPiles ; p++){
        free(gameState->piles[p]);
    }

    free(gameState->piles);
    free(gameState->pileDoneness);
    free(gameState->pileDisabled);
    free(gameState->cards);
}
```

Note that in some cases I may want to deallocate the current gameState but not the previous states.  For example, if I undo a move.

So, when a user starts a new game the gameState is created and returned to my viewController which keeps that reference.  When the user starts another game I first call [MDGameState freeGameState:gameState recurse:YES] to completely clean up the previous gameState and then I create a whole new gameState using [MDGameState newGameStateWithNumberOfPiles:13 andNumberOfCards:52].

I think that I am properly cleaning up after myself.  However, Instruments is telling me that I have memory leaks.  It specifically highlights the bolded line in newGameStateWithNumberOfPiles:andNumberOfCards: the example above.  This happens almost as soon as I start a new game.  It also highlights identical code in the function that makes a copy of the gameState.   I don't understand why that malloc is being highlighted and the two above it aren't.  If I change the order of the mallocs in that function it still highlights the malloc for the cards.

Any chance you have any thoughts on this?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: For the record: you better use objects for that. Objective-C is not much slower than plain C, but more convenient for certain tasks.

Comment: I totally understand. This is also a bit of an experiment to help me better learn C and how it relates to Objective-C.

Comment: Now that's a much better argument. I'm not continuing to split hair in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, ARC does not manage memory allocated with malloc().

You have a leak in the `+freeGameState:recurse:` method because you never call free(gameState), which means every single gameState is leaked.

Correct, MDGameState class will not have a reference to gameState after returning from `+newGameStateWithNumberOfPiles:andNumberOfCards`.

Yes, the caller of `newGameStateWithNumberOfPiles:andNumberOfCards` is responsible for freeing the memory when it is done with the gameState.

Comment: You are right, though it turned out I had two memory leaks.  The other one was in a function that created the cards for gameState->cards.  I allocated an array of null (ok, 0) cards when creating the gameState and then replaced them with a different array of shuffled cards.  I didn't need to allocate the empty array at all and didn't deallocate it when I replaced it, hence the leak. Thank you for your help!